# Trying to find a good camera in my price range

Tags: photography-basics, pricing

I'm 13 years old and just starting to get into photography. It's coming closer to the end of the school year, and my friends want me to do our group photos.

I'm trying to find a camera that will print the photos after I take them and will be kind of small and portable.

I would prefer it to either come with a case or I'll be able to buy it separate from the camera.

Comment: your question might get closed because of it being opinion based / short lived. Might be wise to re-word your question more focused on the points you are looking for and supply more details.

Comment: I think we can read between the lines here and offer a little help without recommending a particular model.

Comment: What about your (or your next) smartphone camera?

Comment: I wish I could use a phone camera, but I currently don't own a phone. I have seen some really good photos done with smartphones, but my father thinks a phone is a waste of time. I thought if I got a camera he would agree with the thought of me not sitting on a phone all day. I just need to find one in a good price range. Thanks for the advice though :)

Comment: @SerenityPickard why did you remove the dollar amount? It makes "in my price range" ambiguous.

Answer (score 12):

> Im 13 years old and just starting to get into photography. I trying to find a good instant camera under $100

Your best bet is probably a point-and-shoot digital camera rather than an "instant" camera. That way you're spending more of your money on the part that records the image rather than the part that prints the image, and you don't have to worry about the expensive consumable cartridges those cameras require. You can also print your photos at any size, whereas the "instant" cameras only give you one or two (tiny and tinier) sizes. You can have your digital photos printed at any local drugstore for maybe 15-20¢ each, or you can use your photos in digital form at no cost at all. Contrast that with Fuji Instax film, which will cost around 70¢ every time you press the shutter button and doesn't give you a digital version of your image.

Check someplace like Amazon to find reasonable deals on compact "point and shoot" digital cameras -- there are plenty in the $100 range. There are a number that offer sensors up to around 20 megapixels for that price. Remember to reserve a bit of your budget for a memory card, but don't spend a lot on those -- you can add more later, and they're always getting faster and cheaper.

Comment: [Used market](https://www.keh.com/shop/cameras/digital-cameras/point-shoot.html?dir=asc&order=price&price=0-100) or asking photographer friends/relatives if they have an old digital P&S they don't use any more and wouldn't mind giving away might work, too. :)